# r - How to create vector with for loops and ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I'm having a problem with nested for loops and ifelse statements. This is my dataframe `abund`:

```
   Species Total C1 C2 C3 C4
1     Blue   223 73 30 70 50
2    Black   221 17 50 56 98
3   Yellow   227 29 99 74 25
4    Green   236 41 97 68 30
5      Red   224 82 55 21 66
6   Orange   284 69 48 73 94
7    Black   154  9 63 20 62
8      Red   171 70 58 13 30
9     Blue   177 57 27  8 85
10  Orange   197 88 61 18 30
11  Orange   112 60  8 31 13
```

I would like to add together some of `abund`’s columns but only if they match the correct species I’ve specified in the vector `colors`.

```
colors <- c("Black", "Red", "Blue")
```

So, if the `Species` in `abund` matches the species in `color` then add columns `C2` through `C4` together in a new vector `minus`. If the species in `abund` does not match the species in `color` then add a 0 to the new vector `minus`.

I'm having trouble with my code and hope it's just a small matter of defining a range, but I'm not sure. This is my code so far:

```
# Use for loop to create vector of sums for select species or 0 for species not selected
for( i in abund$Species)
{ 
  for( j in colors)
  {
    minus <- ifelse(i == j, sum(abund[abund$Species == i, 
       "C2"]:abund[abund$Species == i, "C4"]), 0)
  }
}
```

Which returns this: `There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)`
and this "vector": `minus`    `[1] 0`

This is my target:

```
minus
[1] 150 204 0 0 142 0 145 101 120 0 0
```

Thank you for your time and help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably better done without any loops.

```
# Create the vector
minus <- rep(0, nrow(abund))
# Identify the "colors" cases
inColors <- abund[["Species"]] %in% colors
# Set the values
minus[inColors] <- rowSums(abund[inColors, c("C2","C3","C4")])
```

Also, for what it is worth there are quite a few problems with your original code.  First, your first `for` loop isn't doing what you think.  In each round, the value of `i` is being set to the next value in `abund$Species`, so first it is `Blue` then `Black` then `Yellow`, etc.  As a result, then you index using `abund[abund$Species == i, ]`, you may return multiple rows (ex. `Blue` will give you `1` and `9`, since both those rows `Species == "Blue"`).

Second when you make the statement `abund[abund$Species == i, "C2"]:abund[abund$Species == i, "C4"]` you are not indexing the columns `C2` `C3` and `C4` you are making a sequence starting at the value in `C2` and ending at the value in `C4`.  For example, when `i == "Yellow"` it returns `99:25` or 99, 98, 97, ... , 26, 25.  The reason you were getting those warnings was a combination of this problem and the last one.  For example, when `i == "Blue"`, you were trying to make a sequence starting at both 30 and 27 and ending at both 50 and 85.  The warning was saying that it was just using the first number in your start and finish and giving you `30:50`.

Finally, you were constantly over writing your value of `minus` rather than adding to it.  You need to first create minus as above and index into it for the assignment like this `minus[i] <- newValue`.

Comment: Nice and straightforward!

Comment: You could also just multiply by the logical vector used for `inColors` - `abund$Species %in% colors * rowSums(abund[c("C2","C3","C4")])`

Comment: Thank you very much, @Barker! That worked like a champ. Your explanation was worth a lot and cleared up many misunderstandings I had regarding for-loops. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `ifelse` is vectorized so you usually *don't* need any `for` loops when using it.

I like Barker's answer best, but if you wanted to do this with `ifelse` this is the way:

```
abund$minus = with(abund, ifelse(
    Species %in% colors,  # if the species matches
    C2 + C3 + C4,         # add the columns
    0                     # otherwise 0
))
```

Even though this is just one line and Barker's is 3, on large data it will be slightly more efficient to avoid `ifelse`.

However, `ifelse` statements can be nested and are often easier to work with when conditions get complicated - so there are definitely good times to use them. On small to medium sized data the speed difference will be negligible so just use whichever you think of first.

Comment: Thank you, Gregor. My real dataset has about 11088 rows, so I will keep your advice in mind.

Comment: I would consider that firmly in the "medium sized data" category. Run both and see if you can notice a difference!

Answer (score -1):

```
# Create a column called minus with the length of the number of existing rows. 

# The default value is zero.

abund$minus <- integer(nrow(abund))

# Perform sum of C2 to C4 only in those rows where Species is in the colors vector

abund$minus[abund$Species %in% colors] <- rowSums(abund[abund$Species %in% colors,5:7])
```

Comment: With your edits, this is a buggy version of Barker's answer - nearly identical but you do actually need the condition `abund$Species %in% colors` in the matrix you use `rowSums` on.

Comment: Thanks, @Gregor, for your feedback. I edited my answer accordingly. My previous buggy version explains why I was getting the warning `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length` . My original answer was going on a very convoluted path with `dplyr` and `tidyr`. I do like Barker's elegant answer better as well.

Comment: But this answer is now identical to Barker's answer. What does it add?